# How to enable TLS in Corda 3.1?

Tags: corda

What's the correct way to configure TLS in production on a Corda Node?

We're trying to enable TLS on [CordaApp Sample](https://github.com/corda/cordapp-example) **version 3.1**, but the following error occurs in Corda webserver:

```
[ERROR] 2018-05-03T13:58:16,984Z [main] Main.main - Exception during node startup {}
org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.ActiveMQConnectionTimedOutException: AMQ119013: Timed out waiting to receive cluster topology. Group:null
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:804)
```

`node.conf` file is:

```
myLegalName="O=PartyA,L=London,C=GB"
p2pAddress="localhost:10005"
rpcSettings = {
    address="localhost:10006"
    adminAddress="localhost:10046"
    useSsl=true
    ssl {
        certificatesDirectory="./certificates"
        keyStorePassword="cordacadevpass"
        trustStorePassword="trustpass"
    }    
}
rpcUsers=[
    {
        password=test
        permissions=[
            ALL
        ]
        username=user1
    }
]
webAddress="localhost:10007"
devMode=true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Mike Hearn](https://github.com/mikehearn), from the [Corda Ledger Slack channel](https://slack.corda.net/), RPC SSL is broken in Corda 3.1 and the rework is being made [in this pull request](https://github.com/corda/corda/pull/3039).